# batch files: Delete folders older than 730 days

Tags: batch-file, delete-file, auto-delete

I have read through the threads, but I can't get a batch file working that will delete folders older than 730 days. I want to delete the folder and all its contents. I am using this:

```
forfiles -p "C:\Images\Images\Line 1" -d 730 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
Pause
```

But it just won't work!!

What am I missing? 
Also, please note that I am a Batch File Novice.....

Comment: `@"%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe" /P "C:\Images\Images\Line 1" /D -730 /C "0x22%__AppDir__%cmd.exe0x22 /C If @IsDir==TRUE RmDir /S /Q @Path"`

Comment: As Compo has shown in his code you are missing the minus symbol with your number of days.  It is clearly stated in the help for the `FORFILES` command to use the `+` or `-` and it also says: `"+" is taken as default sign if not specified.`